# Why does the idiom "une grosse légume" mean "VIP"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, registre-familier, société

I was told *une grosse légume* is an idiom for *VIP*. But why so? Why a vegetable would be linked to important people?

Comment: Just a notice: *légume* with its usual meaning is masculine.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: *légume* a changé de genre à travers les siècles. Masculin dans son origine latine, il est employé au féminin en français classique. Au 17ème siècle il commence à être employé aux deux genres; le masculin s'est ensuite imposé presque partout sauf dans le sens métaphorique argotique puis familier de « personnage important ». *(Source Alain Rey)*

Comment: Be careful as when you use *grosse légume* : it's informal language, whereas VIP isn't.

Comment: Same reason as in English: A VIP is also «A big fish»

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Au départ, une *grosse légume* est un officier. C'est de l'argot militaire qui s'est répandu ensuite dans le civil, pour désigner une personne importante. Il semble qu'il y ait plus de détails dans le *Dictionnaire historique des argots français* de [Gaston Esnault](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Esnault) que je n'ai pas.

En 1854, dans son *Voyage en Danemarck, ...*, [Jacques Boucher de Perthes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Boucher_de_Perthes) éprouve encore le besoin de définir le terme (les italiques sont dans l'original) :

> J'abaissai mon chapeau devant cette grande autorité, *cette grosse légume*, comme disent nos soldats quand ils voient passer un officier général ou toute épaulette à graines d'épinards.

Ces [épaulettes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89paulette_%28militaire%29) dites « à [graine d'épinard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/%C3%A9pinard) » (à cause de leur forme) identifient les officiers supérieurs. Elles pourraient bien être à l'origine du terme *légume* (par opposition aux [sardines](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sardine) des sous-officiers), mais l'étymologie est disputée.

C'est peut-être de ces épaulettes que vient aussi l'expression *huile* pour désigner une personne importante, même si là aussi, au-delà de l'origine vraisemblablement militaire, l'étymologie est disputée.

Comment: Pour l'huile, j'aurais imaginé une origine liée au fait qu'elle flotte au-dessus de l'eau.

Answer (score 6):

On peut trouver un début d'explication à cet emploi familier et argotique de *légume*, dans *le  dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey).

> Les connotations négatives ou positives des légumes, souvent contradictoires, reflètent leur statut ambigu.  Être un *légume* (d'après l'anglais *vegetable*), c'est avoir une vie réduite aux fonctions élémentaires, celle des végétaux, ce qui est réducteur appliqué à un animal et plus encore à un être humain. Dans ce cas le langage ne retient que la qualité de végétal et non l'aspect consommable. En revanche, c'est une certaine valeur marchande qui peut être retenue dans l'expression française *grosse légume*, ou elliptiquement *légume*, désignant un personnage important.

À partir de là je me demande si l'emploi du féminin (voir mon commentaire plus haut) ne se serait pas imposé pour renforcer le fait que *légume* dans le sens de « personne importante » désigne une personne (et non un végétal ou quasi végétal).

Dans le *dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) le premier emploi de *légume* dans ce sens métaphorique de « personne importante » date de 1832.

---

We could find the beginning of an explanation in the *dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (Alain Rey & al) in the ambiguous status of vegetables throughout history. Vegetables were the food of the poor peasants until kings and clergy began having vegetable gardens of their own.
Still according to the *dictionnaire culturel en langue française* the use of *vegetable* designating a person (or an animal) reduced to its bare elementary functions  (it was used in English before it was used in French) depicts the vegetable attribute, whereas the use of the word to designate an important person depicts the commercial value of the vegetable.

Comment: still not clear about the logic trace, but well, maybe this is the history of human language, ever evolving...

Comment: Un peu faible, Alain Rey, sur le coup. C'est Esnault qu'il faudrait consulter (tout le monde le cite, mais sans détails).

Answer (score 0):

The [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9gume) gives some clues about the expression :

> **LÉGUME, subst.**
>
> [...]
>
> II. − Subst. masc. ou fém., pop. et fam. Gros(se) légume, une légume. Personne importante ou influente dans un milieu donné. Synon. huile (pop. et fam.).Mon beau-père étant quelque chose dans les « légumes » de l'arrondissement, conseiller cantonal, si je ne me trompe (Verlaine, Œuvres compl., t. 5, Confess., 1895, p. 175).Qui lui aurait dit qu'il deviendrait une légume, un homme en situation et de cabinet (Arnoux, Paris,1939, p. 152):
>   3. D'une humeur massacrante à l'ordinaire, il [un professeur] se montrait charmant le samedi, dans la perspective enivrante de s'en aller bâfrer et boire, le lendemain, chez quelques grosses légumes du commerce bordelais, qui lui avaient confié leurs rejetons. Jammes, Mém.,1922, p. 22.
>   ♦ Loc. verb. vieillie. Être dans les légumes. Occuper un poste important. (Dict. xixeet xxes.).
>
> [...]

Comment: Doesn't say much about the origin of the term...